# I'm not able to seek for all WPF windows

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm using WMI to detect when a process is closed or open, when is open I rise a new thread to open a new window. When the process is closed this window must be closed but I can't closed it because I ain't able to get the windows instance I have.

```
private ManagementEventWatcher EventWatcher(string process)
{
    string query = String.Format(@"
        SELECT * 
        FROM __InstanceOperationEvent 
        WITHIN {0} 
        WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_Process' 
        AND TargetInstance.Name = '{1}'", "1", process
    );

    string scope = @"\\.\root\CIMV2";
    return new ManagementEventWatcher(scope, query);
}


private void GameWatcher() 
{
    ManagementEventWatcher GAMEWatcher = EventWatcher("notepad.exe");

    GAMEWatcher.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(OnEventArrived_Game);
    GAMEWatcher.Start();
}

private void OnEventArrived_Game(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
{
    // If process is open. 
    if (e.NewEvent.ClassPath.ClassName.Contains("InstanceCreationEvent") && !(summonerName is null)) {
        Thread thread = new Thread(RiseWindow);
        thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        thread.Start();
    }


    // If process is closed
    if (e.NewEvent.ClassPath.ClassName.Contains("InstanceDeletionEvent"))
    {
        // Detect windows (This doesn't work and throw the follow exceptions)
        foreach (Window window in Application.Current.Windows)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(window.Title);
        }
    }
}

private static void RiseWindow()
{
    new InGame("Pabloch0", KEY).ShowDialog();
}
```

The code throws the next exceptions, I assume it's because I'm trying detect windows from a thread?

```
'System.InvalidOperationException' in WindowsBase.dll
'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' in mscorlib.dll
```

`System.InvalidOperationException: 'The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.'`

is there any other way to get the windows instance in WPF or close it?

EDIT:

Using Dispatcher I'm able to get only the main windows but not the other one that's opened previously in the thread.

```
Action readWindows = () => {

    foreach (Window window in Application.Current.Windows)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(window.Title);
    }

};

Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(readWindows);
```

Comment: The full exception details could help.

Comment: Theres's not others detaills, or if so I'm not sure how to seek for them. (Added a picture about those exceptions), is weird because the program keep running but in the output you can see clearly that there are some exceptions for everytime I close the notepad.exe.

Comment: From the Debug menu choose Exception settings and select all CLR exceptions. Then VS will break on every exception thrown. Then you should get more details

Comment: Here's it, thanks! @Steeeve `System.InvalidOperationException: 'The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.'` Also this is happening in this line `foreach (Window window in Application.Current.Windows)`

Comment: Try to invoke everything accessing or creating a new UIElement with the [Dispatcher](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatcher?view=windowsdesktop-5.0) of the UI thread to avoid such exceptions.

Comment: Why are you creating a new thread per window? That's complicating things. You need to close the window from it's owning thread.

Comment: @Steeeve As you said I used Dispatcher, but for some reason I'm just able to bring the main windows and not the other one that's opened in the thread. (I've edited the main post with the new code)

Comment: See the [Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.application.windows?view=windowsdesktop-5.0#remarks) on the `Application.Windows` property: *A Window reference is automatically added to Windows as soon as a window is instantiated on the user interface (UI) thread; **windows that are created by worker threads are not added**.*

Comment: If you really need one thread per window, add the new window instances in an own (threadsafe) collection and look it up from there instead of `Application.Current.Windows`